# document list api create failed

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

The request below fails and I am not able to figure out why, any insights?

```
var atom = ["<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>",
            '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:docs="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007">',
            '<category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"',
            ' term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#document"/>',
            '<title>', titleDoc, '</title>',
            '</entry>'].join('');


xhr.open('POST', URI , true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/atom+xml');
//xhr.setRequestHeader('GData-Version', '3.0');                                                                                     
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Length', '0');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + google.getAccessToken());
xhr.send(atom);
```

This is the request/response packet from the servers

```
Request URL:https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Payload
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:docs="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007"><category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#document"/><title>test</title></entry>
Response Headersview source
cache-control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-length:19
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Sun, 01 Jul 2012 06:46:21 GMT
expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server:HTTP Upload Server Built on Jun 14 2012 02:12:09 (1339665129)
status:400 Bad Request
version:HTTP/1.1
```

The repose with gdata Version uncommented, but this still does not create a doc in the google docs

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
status: 200 OK
version: HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-length: 0
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 01 Jul 2012 21:02:16 GMT
expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
location: https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?convert=false&upload_id=AEnB2UoaVeHUGhiIgKm9fL-WL_Fd1DdAAh7rdYDx6G6cseLwHgAMBfkdt42kf9YiKFJ8q9tiZ8vLVUb3Sr-KVUZi01m3vY6ZUw
pragma: no-cache
server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jun 14 2012 02:12:09 (1339665129)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple upload to create an empty file, just replace your url with `https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full` and uncomment the GData-Version header.

Another option (recommended) would be to use the [files.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) method of the new Google Drive API instead.